# "to bring back into use something"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

From [the definition of "resurrect" on Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/resurrect?q=resurrect):

> 1. resurrect something
>    **to bring back into use something** such as a belief, a practice, etc. that had disappeared or been forgotten

I can't see the grammatical structure of the bold part.
Is the "use" a verb?
Shouldn't the "into" be "to" instead, if "use" is used as the infinitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a noun.  In this case it means "the state of being used."

Hence to "bring something back into use" would mean it had been a regular practice, fell out of it, and was brought back.

Comment: Yes. **bring something back into use** seems more idiomatic to me than their **bring back into use something**.

Comment: Yes, but they wanted to add that stuff about "such as a belief" which could get very awkward in the middle.

Comment: Yes, but that's their job :-)

Comment: Oh, so the **something** was the object of **bring back**. It suddenly makes sense to me. Thanks.